# Decode <e8> <e9> etc. characters in R

Tags: r, encoding

How can I decode Base 64 characters like `<e9>` (é) or `<b0>` (°) in a table that was saved with `write.table` without the `UTF-8` option?

Apologies if the answer is obvious, but the R documentation pages mention nothing else than `enc2utf8()` (which does not work here).

**Note:** if there is no solution, I know I can either `gsub()` the whole thing, but that would be long and messy, or I can generate the data again, but that would take some real time (crawler data).

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5282255/602276

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not; it seems to work only on `\366` Unicode encodings, not the `<e9>` encodings that I have.

Comment: Would the [base64 package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/base64/index.html) help? It includes a function `decode()`, which "decodes a file formatted in Base64".

Comment: Tried that too. Perhaps I misunderstood how it works, but I gave a go at the `decode()` command without any luck.